# How to add a background image to category and display image on category page

Tags: categories, post-thumbnails

I have categories on my website. I have to add a background image to each category while creating the category without using any plugin.

I tried some code in function.php and I refer this [link](https://www.blogprocess.com/affect-an-image-to-categories-in-wordpress-without-plugin/).
but it's not working.

```
function my_category_module() {
 add_action ( 'edit_category_form_fields', 'add_image_cat');
 add_action ( 'edited_category', 'save_image');
 }
add_action('init', 'my_category_module');
function add_image_cat($tag){
 $category_images = get_option( 'category_images' );
 $category_image = '';
 if ( is_array( $category_images ) && array_key_exists( $tag->term_id, $category_images ) ) {
 $category_image = $category_images[$tag->term_id] ;
 }
 ?>
 <tr>
 <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="auteur_revue_image">Image</label></th>
 <td>
 <?php
 if ($category_image !=""){
 ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $category_image;?>" alt="" title=""/>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 <br/>
 <input type="text" name="category_image" id="category_image" value="<?php echo $category_image; ?>"/><br />
 <span>This field allows you to add a picture to illustrate the category. Upload the image from the media tab WordPress and paste its URL here.</span>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 }

function save_image($term_id){
 if ( isset( $_POST['category_image'] ) ) {
 //load existing category featured option
 $category_images = get_option( 'category_images' );
 //set featured post ID to proper category ID in options array
 $category_images[$term_id] =  $_POST['category_image'];
 //save the option array
 update_option( 'category_images', $category_images );
 }
 }
```

Displaying on category.php page

```
if(is_category()){
 $category_images = get_option( 'category_images' );
 $category_image = '';
 if ( is_array( $category_images ) && array_key_exists( get_query_var('cat'), $category_images ) ){

$category_image = $category_images[get_query_var('cat')] ;
 ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $category_image;?>"/>
 <?php
 }
 }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I just tried your code that save the image and it works on my test site.

Comment: I am not getting the image option? Where did you get that option?

Comment: @Kaperto, check this image while adding the category https://prnt.sc/pwadap

Comment: the image option is at the bottom of the page when you edit a category. the form for a new category is different from the form for editing a category, this wordpress part is not well optimised.

Comment: @Kaperto, I checked on edit but it's not showing https://prnt.sc/pwal7j

Comment: @Kaperto, I have a doubt, I have a page category.php in my theme page and there I added my code. Should I add in Wordpress category page?

Comment: @Kaperto, now I am getting the image option in category page but How can I add button instead of adding the URL. Once Users click on add image then directly it will open the media tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code. It will add a media button which will get the image url. I have commented the parts that I have deleted or added.

```
function my_category_module()
{
    // this action is deprecated
    //add_action('edit_category_form_fields', 'add_image_cat');

    // Add these actions for edit and add
    add_action('edited_category', 'save_image');
    add_action('create_category', 'save_image');
    add_action('category_edit_form_fields', 'edit_image_cat');
}
add_action('init', 'my_category_module');


function edit_image_cat($tag)
{
    $category_images = get_option('category_images');
    $category_image = '';
    if (is_array($category_images) && array_key_exists($tag->term_id, $category_images)) {
        $category_image = $category_images[$tag->term_id];
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="auteur_revue_image">Image</label></th>
        <td>
            <?php
                if ($category_image != "") {
                    ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $category_image; ?>" alt="" title="" />
            <?php
                }
                ?>
            <br />
            <!-- Add this html here -->
            <input type="text" class="regular-text" id="custom_category_image" name="category_image" value="<?php echo $category_image; ?>">
            <button class="set_category_image button">Set Image url</button>

            <!--
                <input type="text" name="category_image" id="category_image" value="<?php echo $category_image; ?>"/><br />
                <span>This field allows you to add a picture to illustrate the category. Upload the image from the media tab WordPress and paste its URL here.</span>
            -->
        </td>
    </tr>

<?php
}

function save_image($term_id)
{
    if (isset($_POST['category_image'])) {
        //load existing category featured option
        $category_images = get_option('category_images');
        //set featured post ID to proper category ID in options array
        $category_images[$term_id] =  $_POST['category_image'];
        //save the option array
        update_option('category_images', $category_images);
    }
}


// Enquey media elements
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    if (is_admin())
        wp_enqueue_media();
});

// Add JS using admin_footer or enque thorugh hooks
add_action('admin_footer', 'my_footer_scripts');
function my_footer_scripts()
{
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            if (jQuery('.set_category_image').length > 0) {
                if (typeof wp !== 'undefined' && wp.media && wp.media.editor) {
                    jQuery('.set_category_image').on('click', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var button = jQuery(this);
                        var url_input = jQuery("#custom_category_image");
                        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
                            url_input.val(attachment.url);
                        };
                        wp.media.editor.open(button);
                        return false;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: give me sometime to check

Comment: Yes, It's working as expected. I have two doubts. First why used the script at the bottom? Second, How can I show the same button on the add category page?

Comment: The script is to enable media button interaction through JS. You can add the code to a JS file and include it through `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook. To add the same button when adding a new category use `category_edit_form_fields` hook.

Comment: Where should I use category_edit_form_fields hook?

Comment: Sorry. I meant `category_edit_form_fields`. You can add to `my_category_module` like `add_action('category_edit_form_fields', 'add_image_cat');`. Then create `add_image_cat` and add your html code.

Comment: means, I have to add the same code in add_image_cat(). right?

Comment: Similar code. Because when you add a category you don't have a term id yet. So can't check if the image is already added or not as you do in edit_image_cat.

Comment: Oh! Yes, It's working perfectly, Thank you very much. Upvote from my side. I want to know where you learn WordPress? :)

Comment: Mostly 10 years with WordPress manual and Stack Overflow :)

Comment: I have only 2-3 years of experience. I have lots of doubts about WordPress. I have to learn it.

Comment: When you start its a lot of trial and error. But eventually you can master it.

Comment: Yes, I am always trying from my side but no luck.

Comment: Just keep trying.

Comment: Yes, Thank you :)