# How to display categories image in loop homepage WordPress

Tags: categories, images

I saw one answer but in that, they are displaying images in the category or archive page only. Instead of that, I would like to display the category images on the home page with looping all the categories with images.

Here the answer I have seen - [How to add a background image to category and display image on category page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/352455/how-to-add-a-background-image-to-category-and-display-image-on-category-page)

Can anyone help me out from this?

Comment: That code you linked to looks useful. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tring to list the category names on the home/front page with category image.